# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ThemeProvider> above this MyApp Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I've got a problem, my code doesn't work. I've looked through some of the already existing posts, but nothing has worked.

my main.dart looks like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:study_sync/auth/login_or_register.dart';
import 'package:study_sync/theme/theme_provider.dart';



void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeData,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const LoginOrRegister(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

my theme_provider.dart looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dark_mode.dart';
import 'light_mode.dart';

class ThemeProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData = lightMode;

  ThemeData get themeData => _themeData;

  bool get isDarkMode => _themeData == darkMode;

  set themeData(ThemeData themeData) {
    _themeData = themeData;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void toggleTheme() {
    if (_themeData == lightMode) {
      themeData = darkMode;
    } else {
      themeData = lightMode;
    }
  }
}
```

dependencies in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    # When depending on this package from a real application you should use:
    #   google_sign_in: ^x.y.z
    # See https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints
    # The example app is bundled with the plugin so we use a path dependency on
    # the parent directory to use the current plugin's version.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.2
  provider: ^6.1.1
  http: any
  theme_provider: ^0.6.0
```

the error code:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<ThemeProvider> above this MyApp Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.
```

I've tried many different ways, but nothing has worked

Comment: You have to create the provider above the `MaterialApp` widget. Besides, `MaterialApp` has a `themeMode` configuration which you can use to switch between dark, light and system modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Provider.of` gets the instance of `ThemeProvider` you provided higher up the widget tree. In your example, there is no widget above `MyApp`. You need to provide your `ThemeProvider` first like this:

```dart
runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
    create: (context) => ThemeProvider(),
    child: const MyApp(),
  ),
);
```

You will also need to use `ChangeNotifierProvider`. This way, wherever you do `Provider.of` (with `listen: true`, which is the default value) the widget will get rebuilt if the `ChangeNotifier` (which your `ThemeProvider` is) notifies, which is what you want in this example. The `ChangeNotifierProvider` will also take care of disposing your change notifier when disposing itself.

Alternatively, you could use an ordinary `Provider` to provide your class, but you would need to override the [`debugCheckInvalidValueType`](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Provider/debugCheckInvalidValueType.html) check to not complain about this class. But for this case you do not want to do that.